# SQL Query SUM DATEDIFF MAX

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, datediff

I have a problem with a SQL-Query. I want to count the runtime of a used application. But in the database the date value is inserted more then one time. I only need the highest value of the pk_date column and no duplicated entries from the starttime column.

Here is the SQL-Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Standortname,
DATEPART(YEAR,PK_Date) AS Jahr,
DATEPART(month,PK_Date) AS Monat,
Lizenzname,
COUNT(DISTINCT username) AS AnzahlUser,
SUM(DISTINCT DATEDIFF(minute,starttime ,pk_date))  AS RuntimeMinute,
endtime,
pk_date

FROM BenutzerLizenz,Benutzer,Abteilung,Lizenz,Standort
WHERE 
BenutzerLizenz.PK_ID_user=Benutzer.PK_ID_user
AND BenutzerLizenz.PK_ID_lic=Lizenz.PK_ID_lic
AND PK_ID_standort=FK_ID_standort
AND DATEPART(month,PK_Date) = '04'
AND DATEPART(YEAR,PK_Date) = '2013'
AND Lizenzname = 'iman_1st'
AND Standortname = 'Unterlüß'

GROUP BY
 Standortname,
 DATEPART(YEAR,PK_Date),
 DATEPART(month,PK_Date),
 Lizenzname,
 starttime,
 endtime,
 pk_date
```

Here is the result:

```
... RuntimeMinute   starttime                   pk_date
    339         2013-04-11 11:05:00.0000000 2013-04-11 16:44:37.9650000
    346         2013-04-11 11:05:00.0000000 2013-04-11 16:51:25.4800000
    356         2013-04-11 11:05:00.0000000 2013-04-11 17:01:19.9670000
    475         2013-04-11 10:06:00.0000000 2013-04-11 18:01:15.6620000
```

The first three above runtimes are from the same user and session, the last one is from another user and session. I only want to count and sum the last runtimes from the same starttime and the maximum date inserted (pk_date) -> 356 + 475 is the value that I would like to have.

In another similar query all values are accumulated (the columns starttime, endtime, pk_date are not included in it, so the query builds the sum of all runtime values for all users). I tried to use DISTINCT and MAX(pk_date) but it didn't work as expected. Do I have to use Sub-Queries?

Comment: which fields are the user & session? - answer using @d'alar'cop

Comment: @d'alar'cop user is the column username. this is counted in the above select. I want a report e.g. where 3 users use a apllication 800 minutes per month. with a session I mean the lines with the same starttime. like above starttime is 11:05 the user is using the programm from 11:05 till 17:01. I only need the time between the max value of pk_date (only 356 + 475 accumulated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `RANK()` function for this.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT Standortname,
DATEPART(YEAR,PK_Date) AS Jahr,
DATEPART(month,PK_Date) AS Monat,
Lizenzname,
COUNT(DISTINCT username) AS AnzahlUser,
SUM(DISTINCT DATEDIFF(minute,starttime ,pk_date))  AS RuntimeMinute,
endtime,
pk_date,
RANK() Over (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY pk_date DESC) As Rank

FROM BenutzerLizenz,Benutzer,Abteilung,Lizenz,Standort
WHERE 
BenutzerLizenz.PK_ID_user=Benutzer.PK_ID_user
AND BenutzerLizenz.PK_ID_lic=Lizenz.PK_ID_lic
AND PK_ID_standort=FK_ID_standort
AND DATEPART(month,PK_Date) = '04'
AND DATEPART(YEAR,PK_Date) = '2013'
AND Lizenzname = 'iman_1st'
AND Standortname = 'Unterlüß'

GROUP BY
 Standortname,
 DATEPART(YEAR,PK_Date),
 DATEPART(month,PK_Date),
 Lizenzname,
 starttime,
 endtime,
 pk_date,
 username
) tmp where Rank=1
```

The `RANK()` functions ranks each row of a result set in the order defined by `ORDER BY`. Used with `PARTITION BY`, you can further partition the data for ranking.

Since you already have the data that you need, you will partition the result by `username` and rank the `pk_date` in order to get the highest one.

Comment: Thank you alot. it works perfect, when i partionate with starttime, because a user can log in more then one time per day, so the user is the same but the starttime is different (two rank1 lines).

Comment: Another question: Now i get the minutes per user who used an application one more times. i want to accumulate all the runtimes of all user per license (user1 300 min + user2 400 min + user3 100min), but when i add another select and sum this column, i can only display this summed up column and not the other values, because i must use a group by

Comment: Yes. You have to do a `GROUP BY` every time you do an aggregate such as `SUM`. Just `GROUP BY` all other fields that you want to display.

Comment: Now before your query I add SELECT Standortname, Jahr, Monat, Lizenzname, SUM(AnzahlUser) AS Users, SUM(DISTINCT RuntimeMinute) AS RuntimeAkku FROM( SELECT * FROM (... and use group by now I get the different users summed up but when a users logs in 2 times per day he will be counted 2 times. when i use DISTINCT I only get 1 user but this result is wrong.

Comment: I think you actually need `SELECT Standortname, Jahr, Monat, Lizenzname, COUNT(AnzahlUser) AS Users, SUM(RuntimeMinute) AS RuntimeAkku FROM (...) tmp2 GROUP BY Standortname, Jahr, Monat, Lizenzname`

Comment: With `COUNT(AnzahlUser) AS Users` I also get double entries from users who logged in two times per day. I tried `COUNT (DISTINCT AnzahlUser) AS Users` but then I got only one user instead of about 13. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: EDIT: with `COUNT(DISTINCT username)` in the first select i get the right value. thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hey, sorry to get back so late. But I'm glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make a query that only keeps the max(pk_date) for each beginning time and user/session combination. Then add that query to your FROM clause (let's say as adhoc). Then you put in the WHERE clause pk_date = adhoc.pkdate AND username = adhoc.username etc...

Simplified example:

```
(SELECT username, startdate, max(pk_date) as pk_date 
FROM <whatever> 
GROUP BY username, startdate) (= <new>)
```

now, in your main query...

```
SELECT ... FROM ...,<new> adhoc 
WHERE adhoc.username = username 
AND adhoc.startdate = startdate 
AND pk_date = adhoc.pk_date ...
```

Does this help?

Comment: In your first sentence you describe exact what I want to have. But I don't understand the rest - can u give me an example. How can I add a query to the from clause and what is mentioned in the query?

Comment: I have edited - it will depend what DBMS you are using - there may be other ways. etwas klarer?